# How to insert the content of a file into another file before a pattern (marker)?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

`File1` contents:

```
line1-file1      "1" 
line2-file1      "2"
line3-file1      "3" 
line4-file1      "4"
```

`File2` contents:

```
line1-file2     "25"  
line2-file2     "24"  
Pointer-file2   "23"  
line4-file2     "22" 
line5-file2     "21"
```

After the execution of perl/shell script, `File2` content should become:

```
line1-file2     "25"  
line2-file2     "24" 
line1-file1      "1" 
line2-file1      "2"
line3-file1      "3" 
line4-file1      "4" 
Pointer-file2   "23" 
line4-file2     "22" 
line5-file2     "21"
```

i.e  paste the contents of `File1` in `File2` before the line that contains "Pointer".

Comment: Also asked at [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9476933/7552)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243102/using-sed-to-insert-file-content

Comment: I voted already the SO question for closure on this reason, there is no more reason to close this question. Btw, the question is far worse quality on the SO, so logic dictates to close that and not this.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The `sed` utility has a function for that and can do the modification in-place:

```
sed -i -e '/Pointer/r file1' file2
```

But this puts your *Pointer* line above the `file1` contents.  To put it below, delay line output:

```
sed -n -i -e '/Pointer/r file1' -e 1x -e '2,${x;p}' -e '${x;p}' file2
```

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed '/Pointer/e cat file1' file2
```

As per the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Extended-Commands) for the `e [command]`:

> Note that, unlike the r command, the output of the command will be
> printed immediately; the r command instead delays the output to the
> end of the current cycle.

Comment: Could you please explain what `-e 1x -e '2,${x;p}' -e '${x;p}'` do ? I understand that you exchange stuff in the pattern buffer and then print it but I don't know what nor why you added the quiet option `-n` at the beginning.

Comment: @jfg956 Is it possible to just substitute and delete the 'Pointer' part from the original file. This I can figure out with a second sweep of sed, but is it possible to do it in one run?

Comment: to delete the matching line, use `sed -e '/Pointer/{r file1' -e 'd}' file2`

Answer (score 22):

Without using `sed` or `awk`.

First, find the line on which your pattern is:

```
line=$(grep -n 'Pointer' file2 | cut -d ":" -f 1)
```

Then, use 3 commands to output the wanted result:

```
{ head -n $(($line-1)) file2; cat file1; tail -n +$line file2; } > new_file
```

This has the drawback of accessing 3 times `file2`, but might be clearer than a `sed` of `awk` solution.

Answer (score 14):

`awk` makes this fairly easy.
Insert the line before the file:

```
awk '/Pointer/{while(getline line<"innerfile"){print line}} //' outerfile >tmp
mv tmp outerfile
```

To make the inner file print after the `Pointer` line, just switch the order of the patterns (you need to add a semicolon to get the default action), and you can drop the `line` variable:

```
awk '//; /Pointer/{while(getline<"innerfile"){print}}' outerfile >tmp
mv tmp outerfile
```

---

And just because no one has used `perl` yet,

```
# insert file before line
perl -e 'while(<>){if($_=~/Pointer/){system("cat innerfile")};print}' outerfile

# after line
perl -e 'while(<>){print;if($_=~/Pointer/){system("cat innerfile")}}' outerfile
```

Comment: its working, but its getting removed the line containing pointer

Comment: likewise, how to  Paste the contents of file 1 in file 2 **after that "Pointer" containing line  using awk**

Comment: @user1228191 Fixed the first, added the second.

Comment: The 'perl' version doesn't seem to be working. `system("cat innerfile")` outputs the `innerfile` to the console. Am I missing something?

Comment: awk command [gawk '/<body>/{while(getline line<"$HOME/bin/SrunScenario.style"){print line}} //' index.html > new_index.html] just loops and prints millions of lines. gawk V4.2.0 What am I missing here?

Comment: OK; couple of problems: (1) single-quote kept $HOME from expanding; (2) the closing '//' in the script doubled everyting in the output

Answer (score 9):

Use a loop to read the lines in file2. If you find a line starting with `Pointer`, then print out file1. This is shown below:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line
do
    if [[ "$line" =~ ^Pointer.*$ ]]
    then
        cat file1
    fi
    echo "$line"
done < file2
```

Answer (score 9):

An easy job for `ed`:

```
ed -s file1 <<IN
/Pointer/-r file2
,p
q
IN
```

`-r file1` reads in the specified file to after the addressed line, which in this case is the line previous to the first line matching `Pointer`. So this will insert the content of `file2` just once even if `Pointer` occurs on multiple lines. If you want to insert it before each matching line add `g`lobal flag:

```
ed -s file1 <<IN
g/Pointer/-r file2
,p
q
IN
```

Replace `,p` with `w` if you want to edit the file in-place.

---

The accepted `sed` answer does work for most cases but if the marker is on the last line, the command won't work as expected: it will insert the content of `File1` after the marker.
I have initially tried with:

```
sed '/Pointer/{r file1
N}' file2
```

which also works fine (as `r` will do its magic at the end of the cycle) but has the same problem if the marker is on the last line (there's no `N`ext line after the last line). To work around that, you could add a newline to your input:

```
sed '/Pointer/{              # like the first one, but this time even if the
r file1                      # marker is on the last line in File2 it
N                            # will be on the second to last line in
}                            # the combined input so N will always work;
${                           # on the last line of input: if the line is
/^$/!{                       # not empty, it means the marker was on the last
s/\n$//                      # line in File2 so the final empty line in the
}                            # input was pulled i\n: remove the latter;
//d                          # if the line is empty, delete it
}' file2 <(printf %s\\n)
```

This will insert `file2` content before each matching line. To insert it only before the first matching line you could use a `l`oop and just pull in the `n`ext line until you get to end of file:

```
sed '/Pointer/{
r file2
N
:l
$!n
$!bl
}
${
/^$/!{
s/\n$//
}
//d
}' file1 <(printf %s\\n)
```

With these `sed` solutions you lose the ability to edit in-place (but you can redirect to another file).

Answer (score 8):

[Insert file contents into another file BEFORE pattern]

```
sed -i '/PATTERN/r file1' -e //N file2
```

[After Pattern]

```
sed -i '/PATTERN/r file1' file2
```

Comment: `N` works nicely, but not if the PATTERN matches last line of input

Answer (score 5):

There are a few ways to go about this w/ `sed`. One way is a delayed read as is recommended in the accepted answer. It could also be written like:

```
sed -e '$!N;P;/\nPointer/r file1' -e D file2
```

...with a little explicit look-ahead instead of the look-behind implemented elsewhere with the hold buffer. That will inevitably have the same problem with the last line that @don_crissti notes, though, because `N` *does* increment the line cycle and the `r`ead command is applied by line number.

You can get around it:

```
echo | sed -e '$d;N;P;/\nPointer/r file1' -e D file2 -
```

Not all `sed`s will interpret the `-` to mean standard input, but many do. *([POSIX says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) `sed` should support `-` to mean standard-in if the implementer wants `-` to mean standard-in???)*

Another way is to handle the appended content in order. There is another command that *schedules* output in the same way `r`ead does, and `sed` will apply it and `r`ead in the order they're scripted. It's a little more involved though - it entails using one `sed` to `a`ppend the `Pointer` match to the output of another `sed` in its script.

```
sed '   /Pointer/!d                  #only operate on first match
        s/[]^$&\./*[]/\\&/g;H        #escape all metachars, Hold
        s|.*|/&/!p;//!d|p;g          #print commands, exchange
        s|.|r file1&a\\&|;q' file2|  #more commands, quit
        sed -nf - file2              #same input file
```

So basically the first `sed` writes the second `sed` a script, which the second `sed` reads on standard-input *(maybe...)* and applies in turn. The first `sed` only works on the first match for `Pointer` found, and afterward `q`uits input. Its job is to...

1. `s/[]^$&\./*[]/\\&/g;H`

   - Make sure that all pattern chars are safely backslash-escaped because the second `sed` is going to need to interpret every bit it reads literally to get it right. Once that's done, put a copy in `H`old space.
2. `s|.*|/&/!p;//!d|p; x`

   - Tell the second `sed` to `p`rint every input line `!`but the `/&/` one we just pattern-safed; and then to `d`elete all of the same. `p`rint the commands at the second `sed`, then e`x`change the `h`old and pattern buffers to work on our saved copy.
3. `s|.|r file1&a\\&|p;q`

   - The only char we work with here is a `\n`ewline because `sed` will have prepended one when we `H`eld the line before. So we insert the command `r file1` and follow it with our `\n`ewline then the command `a\\` for `a`ppend followed also by a `\n`ewline. All of the rest of our `H`eld line follows that last `\n`ewline.

The script that the first writes looks something like this:

```
/Pointer-file2   "23"/!p;//!d
r file1
a\
Pointer-file2   "23"
```

Basically the second `sed` will print every line but the one the first `sed` sets it up to `a`ppend. For that particular line *two* delayed writes to standard-out are *scheduled* - the first is the `r`ead of `file1` and the second is a copy of the line we want after it. The first `sed`'s doctoring isn't even necessary in this case *(see? no backslashes)* but it is important to safely escape in the way I do here whenever a pattern match is repurposed as input.

Anyway, so... there are a few ways.

Answer (score 3):

This is fairly simple with AWK:

File1 into File2 before pattern = "Pointer"

First load the contents of File1 into a variable

```
f1="$(<File1)"
```

then do the insertion

```
awk -vf1="$f1" '/Pointer/{print f1;print;next}1' file2
```

(Or, if you want to insert File1 after "Pointer")

```
awk -vf1="$f1" '/Pointer/{print;print f1;next}1' file2
```

Answer (score 3):

my preferred way: *templating*.

```
sed 's/CHANGEME/$x/g' origfile | x="$(<file2insert)" envsubst '$x' > newfile
```

This will replace every *CHANGEME* occurence in *origfile* with the content of *file2insert*.
Remove last *g* from sed to replace only the first occurrence of *CHANGEME*.

Comment: How can you use `$x` in your first command, when it is only defined in your second command?

Comment: the "$x" in the first command is only a placeholder to be evaluated by envsubst in the second command.
With single quotes of sed script, $x is not evaluated by your shell.

Answer (score 1):

```
 awk '/Pointer/{system("cat File1")}1' File2
```

Answer (score -2):

```
sed '2r fil1' fil2
```

output

```
line1-file2     "25"  
line2-file2     "24"  
line1-file1      "1" 
line2-file1      "2"
line3-file1      "3" 
line4-file1      "4" 
Pointer-file2   "23"  
line4-file2     "22" 
line5-file2     "21"
```

Comment: There are other `sed`-based options that answer the question about dynamically reading in file2 at the line designated by "Pointer" and not fixed at line 2.