# sed - replace string with file contents

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have two files: `file1` and `file2`.

`file1` has the following contents:

```
---
  host: "localhost"
  port: 3000
  reporter_type: "zookeeper"
  zk_hosts: 
    - "localhost:2181"
```

`file2` contains an IP address (`1.1.1.1`)

What I want to do is replace `localhost` with `1.1.1.1`, so that the end result is:

```
---
  host: "1.1.1.1"
  port: 3000
  reporter_type: "zookeeper"
  zk_hosts: 
    - "1.1.1.1:2181"
```

I have tried:

```
sed -i -e "/localhost/r file2" -e "/localhost/d" file1
sed '/localhost/r file2' file1 |sed '/localhost/d'
sed -e '/localhost/r file2' -e "s///" file1
```

But I either get the whole line replaced, or the IP going to the line after the one I need to modify.

Comment: not sure, but does `cat file1 | sed -e 's/localhost/1.1.1.1/g'` work?

Comment: Look at the `\r` sed command.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790631/use-the-contents-of-a-file-to-replace-a-string-using-sed Has a proper answer using `sed`.

Comment: After messing around with answers here I discovered there is a `r ` command for sed that does this and is way easier to implement and has no issues with / in the file.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32912/201387

Answer (score 29):

Here is a `sed` solution:

```
% sed -e "s/localhost/$(sed 's:/:\\/:g' file2)/" file1
---
  host: "1.1.1.1"
  port: 3000
  reporter_type: "zookeeper"
  zk_hosts: 
    - "1.1.1.1:2181"
```

You should use `sed -i` to make the change inplace.

If you can use `awk`, here is one way to do:

```
% awk 'BEGIN{getline l < "file2"}/localhost/{gsub("localhost",l)}1' file1
---
  host: "1.1.1.1"
  port: 3000
  reporter_type: "zookeeper"
  zk_hosts: 
    - "1.1.1.1:2181"
```

Comment: +1 for `awk`. I imagine `sed` _is_ capable of this, but it will be terribly clumsy. This is where `awk` shines!

Comment: @HalosGhost: It's seem both me and you had misunderstand the OP question, I updated my answer.

Comment: The command substitution for the `sed` solution should be double quoted in case the file contains spaces or glob characters.

Comment: @Graeme: Thanks, updated! Feel free to make an editting.

Comment: Actually, it is a good idea to process the second file too and escape any slashes since these would break the `sed` command.

Comment: You need to escape both `/` and `&` in the substitution.  That's `"$(sed 's:[/\\&]:\\&:g' file2)"`

Comment: I had a multiline pem file with newlines and found this ti work: KEY=$(cat /app/certs/key.pem); awk -v file="$KEY" 'BEGIN{}/\{PRIVATE_KEY\}/{gsub("\{PRIVATE_KEY\}",file)}1' config.json > temp.txt && mv temp.txt config.json . Based on the above, might be improvable but does the job :)

Comment: `sed` option `-i` is not portable. It is valid for GNU but does not work on BSD systems (macOS included).

Answer (score 19):

You can read the file with the replacement string using shell command substitution, before `sed` is used. So `sed` will see just a normal substitution:

`sed "s/localhost/$(cat file2)/" file1 > changed.txt`

Comment: Does this work on multi-lined files and files with special characters?

Comment: @TrevorHickey it doesn't. Sed just fails with an "unterminated `s' command" error.

Comment: Is there any solution for Trevor Hickey's question?

Comment: @TrevorHickey do you mean multiple lines in file2?

Comment: Hey folks check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790631/use-the-contents-of-a-file-to-replace-a-string-using-sed

Answer (score 2):

I also had this "problem" today: how to replace a block of text with the contents from another file.

I've solved it by making a bash function (that can be reused in scripts).

```
[cent@pcmk-1 tmp]$ cat the_function.sh
# This function reads text from stdin, and substitutes a *BLOCK* with the contents from a FILE, and outputs to stdout
# The BLOCK is indicated with BLOCK_StartRegexp and BLOCK_EndRegexp
#
# Usage:
#    seq 100 110 | substitute_BLOCK_with_FILEcontents '^102' '^104' /tmp/FileWithContents > /tmp/result.txt
function substitute_BLOCK_with_FILEcontents {
  local BLOCK_StartRegexp="${1}"
  local BLOCK_EndRegexp="${2}"
  local FILE="${3}"
  sed -e "/${BLOCK_EndRegexp}/a ___tmpMark___" -e "/${BLOCK_StartRegexp}/,/${BLOCK_EndRegexp}/d" | sed -e "/___tmpMark___/r ${FILE}" -e '/___tmpMark___/d'
}

[cent@pcmk-1 tmp]$
[cent@pcmk-1 tmp]$
[cent@pcmk-1 tmp]$ cat /tmp/FileWithContents
We have deleted everyhing between lines 102 and 104 and
replaced with this text, which was read from a file
[cent@pcmk-1 tmp]$
[cent@pcmk-1 tmp]$
[cent@pcmk-1 tmp]$ source the_function.sh
[cent@pcmk-1 tmp]$ seq 100 110 | substitute_BLOCK_with_FILEcontents '^102' '^104' /tmp/FileWithContents > /tmp/result.txt
[cent@pcmk-1 tmp]$
[cent@pcmk-1 tmp]$
[cent@pcmk-1 tmp]$ cat /tmp/result.txt
100
101
We have deleted everyhing between lines 102 and 104 and
replaced with this text, which was read from a file
105
106
107
108
109
110
```

Comment: `sed` is a powerful command; needing to pipe one `sed` into another is rare. I believe that `sed -e "/${BLOCK_EndRegexp}/r ${FILE}" -e "/${BLOCK_StartRegexp}/,/${BLOCK_EndRegexp}/d"` works; do you know of a counterexample?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
join file1 file2
```

and then, remove any unwanted fields.