# "merge" the contents of one shell script file into another

Tags: bash, shell-script, ksh, source

Having a "library" with constants and functions (`lib.sh`), I can include it in my script (`script.sh`)

```
. /myfolder/lib.sh
......
```

Is there a way to merge the included file in the script (i.e. replace `./myfolder/lib.sh` with the content of `lib.sh`)?

Comment: Why are you talking about `bash` in your title if the content refers to `ksh`?

Comment: Can be bash or ksh

Comment: `cat /myfolder/lib.ksh >> script.ksh`

Comment: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141387/sed-replace-string-with-file-contents

Comment: @IporSircer `>>` would put it at the end, where it is too late.

Comment: do you want something specific to this case? (process script.sh and replace ". /myfolder/lib.sh" with the contents of lib.sh), or a more general solution that replaces any `.` or `source` command with the corresponding contents?

Comment: I would go for a general case, where the source might include another source. Something like "compilation" of everything into one file.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak '\|^\. /myfolder/lib\.sh| {
    r /myfolder/lib.sh
    d
}' script.sh
```

What this script does is:

- `\|^\. /myfolder/lib\.sh| { ... }` => locate lines that begin with `. /myfolder/lib.sh` and execute the commands inside the braces
- `r /myfolder/lib.sh` => output the content of `/myfolder/lib.sh`
- `d` => delete the line (`. /myfolder/lib.sh`)

The other lines are left as is of course.

Answer (score 0):

untested: use GNU awk

```
gawk -i inplace '
    $1 == "." {system("cat " $2); next}
    {print}
' script.sh
```