# sed cannot insert if a file ends with empty line

Tags: shell, text-processing, sed

I have a file *uca.xml* (Thunar configuration for custom actions):

```
<?xml encoding="UTF-8" version="1.0"?>
<actions>
<action>
    <!--some code-->
</action>
</actions>
<--blank line here-->
```

Mind that the file **ends with a blank line**

I want a bash command/script to insert a file *customAction.txt* containing:

```
<action>
    <!--custom configuration-->
</action>
```

so it will end looking like:

```
<?xml encoding="UTF-8" version="1.0"?>
<actions>
<action>
    <!--some code-->
</action>
<action>
    <!--custom configuration-->
</action>
</actions>
```

I tried a method given by [jfgagne](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32908/how-to-insert-the-content-of-a-file-into-another-file-before-a-pattern-marker):

`sed -n -i -e '/<\/actions>/r customAction.txt' -e 1x -e '2,${x;p}' -e '${x;p}' uca.xml`

but **it works only if there is at least one character (not a blank line) inserted below the  tag**.

My temporary workaround is a script:

```
echo "someDummyText" >> uca.xml
sed -n -i -e '/<\/actions>/r customaction.txt' -e 1x -e '2,${x;p}' -e '${x;p}' uca.xml
sed -i 's/someDummyText//' uca.xml
sed -i '${/^$/d;}' uca.xml
```

but I believe there is a more elegant, one-line solution with sed. Thanks in advance.

*Note:* this is my very post to the U&L and StackExchange community, so please be lenient with me and do not hesitate to correct me verbosely if I did something wrong. I read the SE FAQ and tried to search for an answer elsewhere with not much luck.

Comment: If you read all the answers there you will find that you could easily do that via `awk`/`perl`/`ed`. Why do you insist on using `sed` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your solution is perfectly adequate.  You can optimise it a bit by replacing the last 2 seds with just one:

```
sed -i '$d' uca.xml
```

After all, you just put the extra line there, so you know what you are removing.

---

If you are looking for alternative solutions, you can use sed to get the line number of the pattern match, and then use that -1 to do the read:

```
if lno=$(sed -n -e '/<\/actions>/=' uca.xml)
then let lno=lno-1
     sed  -i -e "$lno"'r customaction.txt' uca.xml
fi
```

or if you like the ancient but serviceable `ed` command you can do

```
ed -s uca.xml <<\!
?</actions>
-1r customaction.txt
w
q
!
```

Comment: Haven't tried third option with ed but first two options work as expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `sed` read (`r`) command:

```
$ sed '\#</action>#r customAction.txt' uca.txt
<?xml encoding="UTF-8" version="1.0"?>
<actions>
<action>
    <!--some code-->
</action>
<action>
    <!--custom configuration-->
</action>
</actions>
```

There's a blank line at the end of the input file, and this is preserved in the output.  The `r` command will insert the contents of the given file after finding the given pattern. This works as expected on the example data because the single occurrence of the string `</action>`.  If there were more pre-existing actions in the input file, this would not work as expected.

The following would work on a file containing multiple actions:

```
gsed -e '\#</actions>#d' -e '$ r customAction.txt' -e '$ a\</actions>' uca.txt
```

It removes the `</actions>` tag when found and inserts the contents of `customAction.txt` at the end. Then it appends `</actions>` after that.

This way of writing the `a` command requires GNU `sed` (hence `gsed`).