# How to insert the lines from a file into another file after a key word?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have one file that contains the following:

```
10.48.29.68 doggy
10.65.8.184 kitty
10.48.15.104 froggy
```

I need to insert the contents of this file into my hosts file after the line `bc group` in the hosts file.

The hostfile of the server already has hundreds of entries. Bc is a group here in our hosts file. I want code that reads the ip addresses and hostnames in my file above and put those entries in the hosts file below the heading `bc group`.

The new file above should be written in the hosts file after keyword `bc group`.

For example, if my hosts file contains these lines:

```
10.59.12.232 bc4
10.48.29.68 xy9
bc group
10.63.71.136 bc2
10.63.71.214 bc3
```

I need to convert the hosts file to this:

```
10.59.12.232 bc4
10.48.29.68 xy9
bc group
10.48.29.68 doggy
10.65.8.184 kitty
10.48.15.104 froggy
10.63.71.136 bc2
10.63.71.214 bc3
```

I need to append all of the lines from my first file after the line `bc group` in my hosts file, and then continue with the remaining lines in the hosts file.

Comment: Please format your question better - select the file contents and press ctrl+k. Are you wanting to create a new file, or insert into an existing one? How do we decide how to group the lines in general? Do we use all lines or only some?

Comment: I think you are also going to need to provide which groups should be created.  Should there be one `w2k` group or a `w2k12r2` group and a `w2k8r2`, do you have `w2k8r1` servers?  etc...

Comment: i need both ip and hostname to read from one file and then add the entry in existing file which is the hostfile of a server and already having hundreds of entries into it. like Bc is one group here and i want that code to read the ip address and hostname which is written above and put that entry in hosts file below the main heading BC group.

Comment: i just need a code to read the both ip & hostname at a time and add both entries in existing host file under/below specific heading.

Comment: no, no need to decide the group , w2k8rs are servers only, and let suppose there is only one group bc, i just need a code to read the ip address and host name from one file, and write it to another file(hosts file) below a key word BC group. so "BC group" is the main heading under which we need to add the ip address & hostname.

Comment: see related question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32908/how-to-insert-the-content-of-a-file-into-another-file-before-a-pattern-marker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed '/^bc group$/ r file1' hostfile
```

This `sed` command copies the lines from `hostfile` to the output and reads (inserts) the lines of `file1` after any (and all) `bc group` line(s) in `hostfile`.

To save the output in another file, append `> newhostfile` to the command:

```
sed '/^bc group$/ r file1' hostfile > newhostfile
```

However, I recommend this way, which makes a backup with the suffix `.bak`, and edits the file in place:

```
sed -i.bak '/^bc group$/ r file1' hostfile
```

If the `bc group` line appears more than once in the `hostfile`, the lines of `file1` will be inserted more than once.

Comment: this is really nice... i was in confusion that 'sed' command will read either  ip address or hostname at a time because there is a space in between, but it's reading the whole line and appending the new hostfile. Thanks a lot

Comment: @VarunDogra You're welcome.  Please accept the answer by clicking the check mark. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question, and that we have helped you.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need something like this:

```
INPUT_FILE='/path/to/file'
GROUP_NAME='# bc group'
HOSTS_FILE='/etc/hosts'

echo "$GROUP_NAME" >> "$HOSTS_FILE"
while read line; do

    echo "$line" >> "$HOSTS_FILE"

done < "$INPUT_FILE"
```

This script first appends your `$HOSTS_FILE` with the `$GROUP_NAME` (Commented out).  Then it loops through each line of your input file and appends them to the hosts file under your group name.

Comment: using sed command as above, how can i add the new entries after a gap of  n rows from Group name(Main Heading)